# I want to print the words seperated by space from input string

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

l have problem in this code, it stops working when it enters in the inner while loop, it should have printed the single word. For example the string is "My name is jack" the output should have been 
my name is jack, every word after new line

```
int main (void)
{
int i=0,j=0;
char paragraph[1000],word[100];
printf("Enter the paragraph:\n");
gets(paragraph);

while(paragraph[i]!='\0')
{
    int res = isspace(paragraph[i]);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        word[i]='\0';
        printf("\n");
        j=0;
        while(word[j] !='\0')
        {
            printf("%s",word[j]);
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
    }
    word[j] = paragraph[i];
    i++;
    j++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: plz show declaration of paragraph[] and word[]

Comment: I don't see `paragraph` defined anywhere. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: turn on your compiler warnings and mind them. `printf("%s", word[j])` is using a char as if it was a string.

Comment: The way the code is now, `paragraph` is not initialized. As I said, please provide a [mre]. We should be able to copy your code, compile it and get the same error.

Comment: printf("%c",word[j]); gives  me wrong output

Comment: i have edited it please go through one more time

Comment: And where does "My name is Jack" come into the picture?

Comment: @klutt it is just an string i took it for instance, just to print each word in a new line, you are clear yet?

Comment: @Cinya The reason we want a [mre] is that it is extremely common that the problem is in code the asker is not showing.

Comment: i have updated example with complete code, you can run if you want to, as far as i can tell the problem is in inner while loop

Comment: You should turn on the compiler flags `-Wall -Wextra` and read the warnings. They will tell you what's wrong. And do not use `gets`. It has been removed from modern C because it's dangerous. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char newString[10][10]; 
    int i,j,ctr;
       printf("\n\n Split string by space into words :\n");
       printf("---------------------------------------\n");    

    printf(" Input  a string : ");
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);    

    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;  //for next word
            j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n");
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
    return 0;
}
```